# What does each AMS package do?

Tags: packages, amsmath

In my view, any document with a substantial amount of mathematics should load the packages from AMS-TeX. Hence, most of my document's preambles contain

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
```

(I could add to that the non-AMS `mathtools`, etc.). What do each of those packages do? Do I really need to list all of them, or do some of them load others? In particular, does any package load all of them, so that I can simply type

```
\usepackage{ams-everything}
```

shorter than the current list?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Most of the answer was extracted from the **Introduction** sections of the documentation of `amsmath` and `amsthm`:

1. `amsmath` provides miscellaneous enhancements for improving the information structure and printed output of documents containing mathematical formulas. Some of the features provided by this package are:

- The `\DeclareMathOperator` command (through the auxiliary package `amsopn`) to define new "operator name" commands analogous to `\sin` and `\lim`, including proper side spacing and automatic selection of the correct font style and size (even when used in sub- or superscripts).
- Multiple substitutes for the `eqnarray` environment to make various kinds
  of equation arrangements easier to write.
- Equation numbers automatically adjust up or down to avoid overprinting
  on the equation contents (unlike `eqnarray`).
- Spacing around equals signs matches the normal spacing in the `equation`
  environment (unlike `eqnarray`).
- A way to produce multiline subscripts as are often used with summation
  or product symbols.
- The `tag` command, an easy way to substitute a variant equation number for a given equation
  instead of the automatically supplied number.
- An easy way to produce subordinate equation numbers of the form (1.3a)
  (1.3b) (1.3c) for selected groups of equations.
- The `\text` command (through the auxiliary package `amstext`) for typesetting a fragment of text inside a display.
- The `eqref` command, which provides formatting for equation references

2. `amsthm` helps to define theorem-like structures; the introduction to the documentation gives a nice concise description of the package:

> The `amsthm` package provides an enhanced version of LaTeX's
> `\newtheorem` command for defining theorem-like environments. The
> enhanced `\newtheorem` recognizes a `\theoremstyle` specification (as
> in Mittelbach's `theorem` package) and has a `*` form for defining
> unnumbered environments. The `amsthm` package also defines a `proof`
> environment that automatically adds a QED symbol at the end. AMS
> document classes incorporate the `amsthm` package, so everything
> described here applies to them as well.
>
> If the `amsthm` package is used with a non-AMS document class and with
> the `amsmath` package, `amsthm` must be loaded after `amsmath`, not
> before.

3. `amssymb` provides an extended symbol collection. For example, after loading `amssymb` you have the following additional binary relation symbols: `\barwedge`, `\boxdot`,
   `\boxminus`, `\boxplus`, `\boxtimes`, `\Cap`, `\Cup` (and many more), the arrow `\leadsto`, and some other symbols such as `\Box` and `\Diamond`. Another useful feature is the `\mathbb` command to produce blackboard bold characters

Since `amssymb` internally loads `amsfonts`, it's enough to load the former.

As far as I know, there's not a single package loading `amsmath`, `amsthm`, and `amssymb` so all three of them will have to be loaded when using the standard classes (`book`, `report`, `article`).

If one of the document classes of the AMS-collection (`amsbook`, `amsart`) is being used, there's no need to load `amsmath`, or `amsthm`; `amssymb` will have to be explicitly loaded.

Comment: `amsmath` also defines `\eqref` and `\tag`

Comment: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, corrects some bugs, and provides additional useful features, many of which are extensions of the existing `amsmath` syntax.  (relevant also to the answer by @Werner.)

Answer (score 108):

Here is the package dependency hierarchy in terms of the [AMS-LaTeX bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amslatex):

- [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)

  - [`amstext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amstext)

    - [`amsgen`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsgen.dtx) <sup>*</sup>
  - [`amsbsy`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsbsy)

    - [`amsgen`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsgen.dtx) <sup>*</sup>
  - [`amsopn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsopn)

    - [`amsgen`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsgen.dtx) <sup>*</sup>
- [`amssymb`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/amsfonts/source/amssymb.dtx)

  - [`amsfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts) <sup>*</sup>
- [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)

At the moment, there exists no (say) `ams-all` package that would load the entire bundle.

<sup>*</sup> This package has no dependencies.

Comment: @Werner -- `amsthm` does *not* load `amsfonts`.  it does check whether `amsmath` is loaded and makes certain decisions based on that answer (but does not load `amsmath`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Correct, of course. At the time (Oct 2011), could [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) have had a dependency?

Comment: @Werner -- i don't think `amsthm` ever had that dependency. (the last "meaningful" update was in 2004.)  however, since `amsthm` is generated from `amsclass.dtx`, and the three class files also generated from that `.dtx` file *do* load `amsmath`, i can see how one might quite easily arrive at such a conclusion.

Comment: @Werner `amssymb`'s and `amsgen`'s links are broken.