# Is there a way to set math mode font non-italic?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, italic

I read many things about people wanting math mode in sans-serif font and doing crazy things with packages and options to get that, but I did not find anything that would simply make my math mode font non-italic.

**Is there an (easy) way to set math mode font to be non-italic?**

And is there a way to do that globally for the whole document?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

On a case-by-case basis, it is possible to typeset text within math mode using `\textrm{...}` or `\mathrm{...}`, the latter being used predominantly for typesetting units or symbols and not pure text (since it gobbles spaces that are not escaped). `\mbox{...}` is another alternative to `\textrm{...}`, since it resets its contents to text mode by default. Here are some examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is a formula: $x=\exp(\log \mathrm{x})$

Here is another: $\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t = \textrm{famous identity}$
\end{document}​
```

The above font changes do not work that well in general, since switching to a different font when using sub- and superscripts, say, does not always scale as expected. There are ways around it though. For example, using `\text{...}` from the [`amstext` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amstext) (automatically loaded by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) - see the [AMS package dependencies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32103/5764)), which switches to the appropriate font size via `\mathchoice`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
% amsmath loads the amstext package by default
\begin{document}
Here is a formula: $x=y^{abc}$

Here it is again: $x=y^{\mbox{abc}}$

Compare that to: $x=y^{\text{abc}}$
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Note that when using an environment created by `\newtheorem`, the default text is emphasized. So if you want non-italicized text in math using `\text` that appears in a theorem/axiom/etc, you may have to *re*-emphasize it by surrounding it in `\emph`. This additional `\emph` acts to turn off italics in order to "emphasize" text that's sitting in default italics.

Answer (score 37):

The results are not always perfect, but `mathastext` is what you're looking for, when you want to set globally the math font to upright (or to use another completely different font, check the documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
Here is a formula: $x=\exp(\log x)$

Here is another: $\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t = 1$

What about Greek? $\alpha+\beta$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't tell anybody that I recommended it. :) Indeed I *strongly* advise not to do evil things like printing all math upright. :)

Comment: So your advise is typing `\mbox{...}` before every math line?

Comment: @cebe No, my advise is to use italics for math as typographers have done for centuries. If you *really* want to use roman letters for math, then `mathastext` is the right tool.

Comment: Reluctantly I'm casting a vote for this answer:-) The `mathastext` package lets you cheat on *proper* math typesetting but sometimes it looks nice.

Answer (score 22):

Probably not what you are looking for, but you could use the Euler math font which is an upright math font (non-italic).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
This is some text in Palatino with an inline equation $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$
followed by an equation:
\begin{equation}
  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1 + x^2}\mathrm{d}{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Just don't use them with Computer Modern.  (My example here uses Palatino for the text font.)

[image: Sample output]

Comment: So far the only asthetic solution for upright maths :-)

Answer (score 7):

Also if you're writing the same thing over, like units, I just created a new command and used it every time:

```
\newcommand{\inch}{\ensuremath{\,\textrm{in.}}}
```

This returns "in." without italics, and a space after the number. :)

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{19\inch-2.75\inch}{2} + 0.54 \inch = 8.125\inch + 0.54\inch = 8.665\inch
\label{eq:outeredgemodel}
\end{equation}
```

becomes:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Some packages (`MinionPro`, `mathdesign`, `fourier`, `kpfonts`) have an option "frenchmath” (the exact name depends on the package), which typesets uppercase roman letters and all greek letters  upright, *and* takes care of the metrics.