# How to make all the text in math mode non-italic

Tags: equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to set math mode font non-italic?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39515/is-there-a-way-to-set-math-mode-font-non-italic)

I learned, that I can change the equation to not-italic, using `$\mathrm{text}$`. But how to make all the equations non-italic without adding `\mathrm` into all of them?

I tried `\everymath{\mathrm}`, but it failed.

Comment: When you mean with equation you mean what? The expression? or the text?

Comment: Check out this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39515/is-there-a-way-to-set-math-mode-font-non-italic