# Automatic upright math when text is in italic

Tags: math-mode, theorems, italic

This is in a way a follow-up to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39515/is-there-a-way-to-set-math-mode-font-non-italic) about upright math.

I would like to have upright math (essentially variable names) when I use a theorem-like environment with statement in italic.  This used to be done that way in certain 19th century mathematical publications, and I would like to reproduce that look.

1. I could use \mathrm everywhere I need it in the formulas.
2. I could remove the $...$ everywhere only isolated letters are used in the statement and surround them with appropriate commands.
3. I could use the `mathastext` LaTeX package with its "subdued" option

But

1. It's a pity to surcharge all the formulas for the special case of theorems
2. It's also not great to *un-TeX* math variables in theorems as well, also bad for proofreading, cuting and pasting.
3. The use of the `mathastext` package is quite heavy in consequences because of all its interaction with mathfonts, mathversions and seems a bit of a risk for a large document using already many packages. As its author himself writes:

   > Without the subdued option, the mathastextification applies by default to the whole of the document (and one may also define additional math versions in the preamble); with the **subdued** option the mathastextification is done only in math versions distinct from the standard and bold ones.
   >
   > The previous description is in fact a bit optimistic: mathastext was not written initially in order to allow its action to be completely cancelled, and achieving this would require a complete rewrite of large portions of the code. In order to really have the displayed math (almost) as if mathastext had not been loaded, one must at a minimum also use the option defaultmathsizes. This does not quite suffice,[...]

So, is there a simple way I could define a theorem environment where (simple) math would be upright ?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to jfbu's answers, here is a visual illustration. The case I wanted is the last one.

[image: Demonstration of various combinations of italic and upright for theorems]

Comment: If you have a font with `OML` encoding and upright latin letters and greek letters, then it should be easy enough using `\DeclareMathVersion` to declare a math version called `myuprightmath` for example and then `\SetSymbolFont {letters){myuprightmath}<font specification>`. Else, one has to use two fonts, one with upright Greek letters and the other one with upright Latin letters. And this means a bunch of `\DeclareMathSymbol` to re-assign the Greek letters to the desired font, now distinct from the one for Latin letters.

Comment: That is something like `greekletters` should be declared with `\DeclareSymbolFont`, and in the normal and bold math versions one would use the standard font for `greekletters` whereas in the special `myuprightmath` math version one would then have `greekletters` (and `letters`) map to the two upright fonts.

Comment: What was done in 19th century typography isn't necessarily worth reproducing. This is one case.

Comment: @egreg : although this is perhaps marginal, one use I have of TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt, etc. is to reproduce faithfully extracts of the scientific literature of the past.

But if one remembers that the use of italic for mathematical variables was precisely to make them stand out from the surrounding normal text, then you can justify reversing the pattern when surrounded by italic text.

Comment: @jfbu : thanks for your comments about OML and LGR encoding. I will need this kind of things anyway because my document contains both vanilla LaTeX math typesetting and several old-style math parts.

Comment: @egreg I am curious about the historical roots of the italic thing. A wild guess: I suspect a big influence of the integral sign, the stylized `S` of Leibniz. It was to be written as a very slanted very big thing, and could there have been some sort of contagion among typographers to the other letters? do you know of an informed historical reference on mathematical typography?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I explained in the comments. I also had to declare a Symbol Font also for the Latin letters, because there are some things in standard LaTeX, like `rightharpoonup` which are in letters; and we don't want to reassign them to a font with another encoding.

Update: added at the end the necessary code for `LGR` which was mentioned in comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont {greekletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont {latinletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathVersion {upright}
\SetSymbolFont {latinletters}{upright}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont {greekletters}{upright}{U}{txmia}{m}{it} % using the upright
                                % Greek letters provided with the txfonts
                                % package 

\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{b}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`b}
\DeclareMathSymbol{c}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`c}
\DeclareMathSymbol{d}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`d}
\DeclareMathSymbol{e}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`e}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`f}
\DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`g}
\DeclareMathSymbol{h}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`h}
\DeclareMathSymbol{i}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`i}
\DeclareMathSymbol{j}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`j}
\DeclareMathSymbol{k}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`k}
\DeclareMathSymbol{l}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`l}
\DeclareMathSymbol{m}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{n}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{o}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`o}
\DeclareMathSymbol{p}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{q}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{r}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`r}
\DeclareMathSymbol{s}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`s}
\DeclareMathSymbol{t}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`t}
\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`u}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`v}
\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`w}
\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{y}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{C}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{D}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{E}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{F}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{G}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{H}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{K}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{L}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{M}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{O}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{P}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Q}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{R}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{S}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{T}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{U}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{V}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`V}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`W}
\DeclareMathSymbol{X}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}{\mathalpha}{latinletters}{`Z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"27}

\begin{document}

This is standard: $\alpha^n+\beta^n+x^n+y^n=z^n$.

\mathversion {upright}

This is upright: $\alpha^n+\beta^n+x^n+y^n=z^n$.

\mathversion {normal}

This is standard:  $\alpha^n+\beta^n+x^n+y^n=z^n$.


\end{document}
```

[image: upright]

Here is now what one can do for `LGR`. It got complicated as I wanted also to define `\Alpha`, `\Beta`, etc... which usually come from the Latin font, but as they are in the `LGR` encoded font, I needed to make them available in the standard non-upright math as well (and they are then picked in the `cmr` font, assuming standard set-up).

```
\DeclareFontEncoding {LGR}{}{}
\SetSymbolFont {greekletters}{upright}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n} 

% (the LGR encoded CMR font comes with the cbfonts package, and is
% pre-installed at least in TeXLive and presumably also other TeX
% distributions)

% This list defines also `capital' Greek letters,
% including the ones usually represented by Latin letters.
% missing: \varphi, \varepsilon, \varpi, \vartheta, \varrho

%% 'uppercase'
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Alphalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{65}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Betalgr}    {\mathord}{greekletters}{66}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Gammalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{71}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Deltalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{68}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Epsilonlgr} {\mathord}{greekletters}{69}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Zetalgr}    {\mathord}{greekletters}{90}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Etalgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{72}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Thetalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{74}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Iotalgr}    {\mathord}{greekletters}{73}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Kappalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{75}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Lambdalgr}  {\mathord}{greekletters}{76}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Mulgr}      {\mathord}{greekletters}{77}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Nulgr}      {\mathord}{greekletters}{78}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Xilgr}      {\mathord}{greekletters}{88}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Omicronlgr} {\mathord}{greekletters}{79}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Pilgr}      {\mathord}{greekletters}{80}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Rholgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{82}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Sigmalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{83}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Taulgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{84}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Upsilonlgr} {\mathord}{greekletters}{85}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Philgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{70}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Chilgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{81}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Psilgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{89}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Omegalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{87}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\Digammalgr} {\mathord}{greekletters}{195}
%% 'lowercase'
\DeclareMathSymbol {\alphalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{97}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\betalgr}    {\mathord}{greekletters}{98}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\gammalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{103}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\deltalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{100}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\epsilonlgr} {\mathord}{greekletters}{101}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\zetalgr}    {\mathord}{greekletters}{122}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\etalgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{104}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\thetalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{106}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\iotalgr}    {\mathord}{greekletters}{105}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\kappalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{107}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\lambdalgr}  {\mathord}{greekletters}{108}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\mulgr}      {\mathord}{greekletters}{109}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\nulgr}      {\mathord}{greekletters}{110}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\xilgr}      {\mathord}{greekletters}{120}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\omicronlgr} {\mathord}{greekletters}{111}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\pilgr}      {\mathord}{greekletters}{112}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\rholgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{114}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\varsigmalgr}{\mathord}{greekletters}{99}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\sigmalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{115}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\taulgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{116}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\upsilonlgr} {\mathord}{greekletters}{117}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\philgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{102}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\chilgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{113}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\psilgr}     {\mathord}{greekletters}{121}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\omegalgr}   {\mathord}{greekletters}{119}
\DeclareMathSymbol {\digammalgr} {\mathord}{greekletters}{147}

\makeatletter

% \let\Alphastd A\let\Betastd B\let\Epsilonstd E\let\Zetastd Z%
% \let\Etastd N\let\Iotastd I\let\Kappastd K\let\Mustd M%
% \let\Nustd N\let\Omicronstd O\let\Rhostd P\let\Taustd T%
% \let\Chistd X\let\Digammastd F%
% but we wan't them upright (as the other capital Greek letters), hence:
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Alphastd}  {\mathord}{operators}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Betastd}   {\mathord}{operators}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Epsilonstd}{\mathord}{operators}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Digammastd}{\mathord}{operators}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Etastd}    {\mathord}{operators}{`H} % not sure here
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Iotastd}   {\mathord}{operators}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Kappastd}  {\mathord}{operators}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mustd}     {\mathord}{operators}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Nustd}     {\mathord}{operators}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omicronstd}{\mathord}{operators}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Rhostd}    {\mathord}{operators}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Taustd}    {\mathord}{operators}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Chistd}    {\mathord}{operators}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zetastd}   {\mathord}{operators}{`Z}

\let\digammastd f% <- not satisfactory ?
\let\omicronstd o%

\@for\@tempa:=alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,%
  iota,kappa,lambda,mu,nu,xi,pi,rho,varsigma,sigma,%
  tau,upsilon,phi,chi,psi,omega,Gamma,Delta,Theta,Lambda,%
  Xi,Pi,Sigma,Upsilon,Phi,Psi,Omega\do{\expandafter\let
  \csname\@tempa std\expandafter\endcsname\csname\@tempa\endcsname}%

\newcommand*\lgrgreek{%
  \@for\@tempa:=alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,%
  iota,kappa,lambda,mu,nu,xi,omicron,pi,rho,varsigma,sigma,%
  tau,upsilon,phi,chi,psi,omega,digamma,Digamma,Alpha,Beta,%
  Gamma,Delta,Epsilon,Zeta,Eta,Theta,Iota,Kappa,Lambda,Mu,Nu,%
  Xi,Omicron,Pi,Rho,Sigma,Tau,Upsilon,Phi,Chi,Psi,%
  Omega\do{\expandafter\let\csname\@tempa\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname\@tempa lgr\endcsname}}%

\newcommand*\stdgreek{%
  \@for\@tempa:=alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,%
  iota,kappa,lambda,mu,nu,xi,omicron,pi,rho,varsigma,sigma,%
  tau,upsilon,phi,chi,psi,omega,digamma,Digamma,Alpha,Beta,%
  Gamma,Delta,Epsilon,Zeta,Eta,Theta,Iota,Kappa,Lambda,Mu,Nu,%
  Xi,Omicron,Pi,Rho,Sigma,Tau,Upsilon,Phi,Chi,Psi,%
  Omega\do{\expandafter\let\csname\@tempa\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname\@tempa std\endcsname}}%

\newcommand*\checkgreekletters{%
  \@for\@tempa:=alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,%
  iota,kappa,lambda,mu,nu,xi,omicron,pi,rho,varsigma,sigma,%
  tau,upsilon,phi,chi,psi,omega,digamma,Digamma,Alpha,Beta,%
  Gamma,Delta,Epsilon,Zeta,Eta,Theta,Iota,Kappa,Lambda,Mu,Nu,%
  Xi,Omicron,Pi,Rho,Sigma,Tau,Upsilon,Phi,Chi,Psi,%
  Omega\do{\makebox[.75em]{$\csname\@tempa\endcsname$}, }}

\makeatother
\stdgreek % initializes \Alpha, etc...


\begin{document}

This is standard: $\alpha^n+\beta^n+x^n+y^n=z^n$.

\checkgreekletters

\mathversion {upright}\lgrgreek

This is upright: $\alpha^n+\beta^n+x^n+y^n=z^n$.

\checkgreekletters

\mathversion {normal}\stdgreek

This is standard:  $\alpha^n+\beta^n+x^n+y^n=z^n$.

\checkgreekletters

\end{document}
```

[image: upright with lgr]

Comment: There are also nice upright Greek letters in the `LGR` encoded `cmr` font. But the numbers to use as last entry of `\DeclareMathSymbol` have all to be changed to use this `LGR` encoding.

Comment: thanks a lot for this easy to understand solution. It will do nicely for my intended use.

Comment: with the `lgr` variant, with `CM` fonts, it appears that the uppercase Greek glyphs are the same in the  `LGR` and in the `OT1` fonts. So, it would be simpler to not define both  `\Alphastd` and `\Alphalgr` but just `\Alpha` (to be an `A` from `OT1`), and not touch `\Gamma` etc... only lowercase letters need to be treated as in my answer. However for some other fonts in `LGR` encoding than `CM` one needs to do as in my answer.

Comment: and were it not for the fact that `\DeclareMathSymbol` is made preamble-only by the LaTeX kernel, we could spare defining all these control sequences `\alphalgr`, `\alphastd` etc... (using directly `\mathcode` is possible but then one needs to recover the family number, and perhaps worry about unicode engines, etc... )

Comment: thanks for this extension of the idea so that all the Greek capitals can be selected. As for the constraints of \DeclareMathSymbol, I don't mind at all. I feel it is cleaner and more portable.