# Delta with an angular tail

Tags: symbols, greek

Is there a way to type in a delta shape with an angular tail as opposed to the standard curvy tail of the `\delta` command?

What I am after is what shows up on the first line of the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_(letter), where they distinguish between upper case `\Delta`, lower case 'angular-tailed delta' (what I am after) and lower case 'curvy-tailed delta' (what you get with the `\delta` command).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Can you show one example of how such a symbol is supposed to look?

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of the symbol produced by `\partial`?

Comment: Thanks. I have added the look I am searching in the question. I could use `\partial` as an alternative. However, in the text I am typing, I am already using `\delta` for a dimension parameter, `\partial` for actual derivation and searching for another sort of delta for the Dirac... I I copy-paste the wiki article, one that directly uses the unicode-ascii angular delta, I get the same typeset output as with the `\delta` command.

Comment: Oh, so you mean `\Delta`...

Comment: I think, the character you are looking for is actually a typographic variation used in some sans-serif fonts. It is actually the very same character as `\delta`. It is just the font that renders it differently (namely with a sharp edge instead of a rounded tail, for example IBM Plex Sans).

Comment: Hello Jasper. Is there a way to force (with a local command) LaTeX to return a delta with such a modified typeset? If I enclose the delta with `\mathsf` or `\textsf`, it does not change anything.

Comment: It seems wikipedia uses the default sansserif font from your browser to display  the δ in this table. You can probably look it up in the preferences of your browser. For example mine uses Helvetica to render this table.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of getting different types of delta using txfonts, upgreek and textgreek packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{textgreek}



\begin{document}
Regular delta: $\delta$.

Regular Bold and upright delta $\boldsymbol{\deltaup}$. %requires txfonts package

Using updelta: $\updelta$. %requires upgreek package

Using updelta bold: $\boldsymbol{\updelta}$. %requires upgreek package

Text greek delta in text \textdelta. %requires textgreek package

Text greek delta in text {\bf \textdelta}. %requires textgreek package
 
\end{document}
```

This is what I get.

[image]

You can also find more options by looking at different fonts.These lists from other questions might be helpful.

[A Whole List of Math Fonts for Greek Letters in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487710/a-whole-list-of-math-fonts-for-greek-letters-in-latex)

[Automatic upright math when text is in italic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/automatic-upright-math-when-text-is-in-italic)

Then you might be able to use the approach used in this answer:

[Change font of single greek letter in math environment for all equations (classicthesis.sty)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509836/change-font-of-single-greek-letter-in-math-environment-for-all-equations-classi)

Comment: Many thanks. Since I am quite rubbish at pure LaTeX, I work within the LyX environment. I am trying to add somethings in the preamble, but it is ignored...

Answer (score 3):

The symbol I think you are looking for is just a `\delta`. But in some fonts, particularly some sans-serif fonts, the character has the flat top.

For example, iwona:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon$

\end{document}
```

Kurier:

[image]

```
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `unicode-math` package makes both `\delta` and `\partial` available in many different alphabets:

In Latin Modern math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[ \symit{\delta} \, \symup{\delta} \, \symbfit{\delta} \, \symbfup{\delta} \, \symbfsfit{\delta} \, \symbfsfup{\delta} \]
\[ \symit{\partial} \, \symup{\partial} \, \symbfit{\partial} \, \symbfup{\partial} \, \symbfsfit{\partial} \, \symbfsfup{\partial}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]