# How to change default font style in math mode?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

In my latex document I would like to change the default font style (i.e italic) of the math mode to normal shape.

By now I am using **\mathrm** but is there a way to set the style of a specific math snippet?

Something like this:

```
\begin{align}[font=\rmfamily]
...
\end(align)
```

Answer (score 5):

Really strange demand..

Changing math font may help you---font Euler can be loaded by `\usepackage{euler}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    E = mc^2.
\]
\end{document}
```

In addition, `\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}` may be what you are looking for, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39520/38350):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    E = mc^2.
\]
\end{document}
```

Or, if you want to use your own font, have a look at the section 3.4 "Declaring math alphabets" of document fntguide (type `texdoc fntguide` in terminal window).

Indeed, I *strongly* advise not to do evil things like printing all math upright.. PLUS ONE.

Comment: Printing math upright? Something that's easy to do with the-program-I-never-mention-the-name-of. `;-)` Not reader's friendly at all.

Comment: Hah, that's really evil, acting like "I'm shy, don't look at me".. lol @egreg

Comment: you should load `mathastext` *after* `amsmath`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put these in your preamble:

```
\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\mathgroup0}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\mathgroup0}
```

It doesn't look good though, so I guess you may also want to change font.