# French math style with default font

Tags: math-mode, french

Edit: Okay, I found it, just needed more focus on the related entry. The package `mathastext` called with the `frenchmath` option does the job.

The time for my first question to stackexchange could have been delayed...

Original question:

I've realized that French typography uses a different style for mathematics,  namely upright uppercase roman letters and lowercase greek letters (roman lowercase remaining in italic), while default LaTeX is italic.
What I want is to use this style with the default math font.

I found far less resources on the Web than I expected, like [this one](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/math-font-selection.xhtml#math-style), which introduces math font packages with options for French (or ISO) math style. Nevertheless I'm quite unhappy with the general look of these fonts, not mentioning the fact that [unicode-math](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/unicode-math.html) seems to clash with amssymb.

[This related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139107/how-to-change-default-font-style-in-math-mode) has been answered with:

> Simply put these in your preamble:
>
> ```
> \everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\mathgroup0}
> \everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\mathgroup0}
> ```
>
> It doesn't look good though, so I guess you may also want to change font.

which I guess is interesting for my issue, but not explained a single bit and I don't know how, or if, I can adapt it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of adding the answer into the question, you can wait a few hours and answer your own question in the appropriate place. :-)

Comment: the font packages `kpfonts` and `mathdesign` both have options to get French style in math mode.

Comment: @jfbu: Well I didn't mentioned it, but I did try these packages, `kpfonts` modifies the font and `mathdesign`, with the appropriate `uppercase=upright` and `greeklowercase=upright` options didn't work at all (?). I must admit I only skimmed the documentations though.

Comment: The `MinionPro`package also has such an option.

Comment: @Idl for `mathdesign` possibly some text font needs to be installed like `URW Garamond`. But yes both `kpfonts` and `mathdesign` are font packages (`kpfonts` providing its own fonts for text and mathematics).

Answer (score 3):

You wrote,

> not mentioning the fact that `unicode-math` seems to clash with `amssymb`

What's the basis for this claim? The packages get along fine as long as `amssymb` is loaded first.

If you can use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document, specifying the option `math-style=french` while running `\setmathfont` lets you achieve all of your locale-related formatting objectives.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newcommand\blurb{%
  abcd \quad ABCD \quad \gamma\delta\phi\psi\omega 
  \quad \Gamma\Delta\Phi\Psi\Omega}

\begin{document}
Four math styles:

$\begin{array}{@{} ll @{}}
\toprule
$TeX$     & \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[math-style=TeX]\blurb \\
$ISO$     & \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[math-style=ISO]\blurb \\
$french$  & \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[math-style=french]\blurb \\
$upright$ & \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[math-style=upright]\blurb \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [newtxmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) package has a `frenchmath` option. `newtx` is a Times-style font, but also supports `libertine`, `minion`, `stix2`, and other math fonts. `newtx` is also compatible with LuaLaTeX and XeTeX (see details in package documentation).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \Phi(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/2} \, dt \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

If your text is entirely in french you are better off with the [frenchmath](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/frenchmath) package which implements all french-specific math typesetting.