# How to make everything bold in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, bold, boldmath, bm

I want to write everything in math mode as bold characters. I know that with `bm` package I can do that. Here is my example code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,amsmath}

\begin{document}
$E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$. \newline
\begin{equation}
E =mc^2
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} 
\end{align}


\hrule
% I don't want to use \bm{} everytime.
$\bm{E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2}$. \newline
\begin{equation}
\bm{E =mc^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
\bm{\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I don't want to write `\bm{}` for every mathematical expression. I want bold characters whenever I write any mathematical expression inside `$$` or `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. Is there any way around?

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139107/how-to-change-default-font-style-in-math-mode

Comment: Basically you could use `\everymath{}` with the appropriate switching command.

Comment: Another related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/change-math-font-only-in-some-parts-of-a-document

Comment: Issue `\boldmath` in the preamble. But you shouldn't.