# Change the default font of the equation environment and math mode globally

Tags: fonts, equations, pdftex, environments, mathcal

Is it possible to change the default font in the equation environment and also in math mode globally to `mathcal` or `mathscr`?

By this I mean that if I typeset `$...$`, or `$$...$$` or

```
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{theorem}
my description here
    \begin{equation}
    ...
    \end{equation}
\end{theorem}
```

The default font used in the equations will be either `mathcal` or `mathscr`?

I am compiling using `pdflatex`.

I read the following post

[How to change default font style in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139107/how-to-change-default-font-style-in-math-mode)

however I wansn't able to use it to solve this issue (possibly due to conflicts with the existing packages in the custom template I have to use).

Here is an example:

If I type

```
\begin{equation}
    p(x) = (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2} \exp \bigg\{ \frac{-1\frac{1}{2} \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2} \bigg\}
\begin{equation}
```

I would like the result to appear like this:

[image]

(Image taken from a pdf document I have. I don't know the original author of it so I can not contact them).

Comment: `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` only work for capital letters, so this would give bad results if you have any lower case letters in your math expressions. To solve this you would need to check automatically which parts of your math are upper case and which are not, that would be very complicated. So it's probably easier to just type the calligraphic or script letters manually. You could consider defining some macro's to save on typing, for example `\def\clA{\mathcal{A}}` so you can type `\clA` every time you need a calligraphic A.

Comment: @Marijn thank you for the response. Perhaps I wasn't clear about the requirement. I have added an example to illustrate what I mean. I have a pdf document where the author someone has managed to do it but I don't know how they did it and I also don't know the author so I can not contact them to inquire.

Comment: That might be a custom math font with XeLaTeX, you could check the pdf properties (one of the menu items in your pdf viewer) to see which compiler was used and which fonts are in the document. You can get something similar (although not entirely the same) in pdfLaTeX with `\usepackage{mathpazo}`.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem, since the symbols from your desired output are not actually from `\mathcal` or `\mathscr`, but the `range=` option of `\setmathfont` from `unicode-math` does have a syntax to remap math alphabets such as `\mathit` and `\mathcal`. Furthermore, it has lowercase `\mathcal` Latin letters. There is no Greek `\mathcal` alphabet, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the output with something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
p(x) = (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2} \exp \biggl\{ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2} \biggr\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer `garamondx` for the text fonts, so I loaded it after `mathdesign` to override its selection of the text font.

[image]

This has of course nothing to do with `\mathcal`, that denotes a specific math alphabet for special symbols.