# non-italic font for equation when we use "Subscript"?

Tags: fonts, equations, subscripts, italic

I read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39524/148579) about non-italic font for equation, however, it does not work when we use `Subscript` in our equation:

```
\begin{equation}
  \mbox{$ abc_{d} $} 
\end{equation}
```

Is there a solution to show such an equation without italic font?

Comment: I think you want to use `\mathrm` here: `abc_{\mathrm d}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you want just the subscript to be upright, then you should use `\mathrm` here instead of the `\mbox` technique, since the `\mbox` will not preserve the fontsize decrease that you expect in the subscript. Note also, you don't need the `$` inside the `equation` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  abc_{\mathrm{d}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you want the whole expression to be upright, simply wrapping it in `\mathrm` will work, but it's likely that there are better ways to achieve what you want, e.g. using the `amsmath` command `\DeclareMathOperator` to create custom operators that should be rendered upright.  See the following question for more detail on this:

- [Is there a preference of when to use \text and \mathrm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19502/2693)

Comment: Gets my upvote :)

Comment: Please brace the argument.  `$abc_{\mathrm def}$` might yield unexpected results for a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

### In Modern Toolchains

With `unicode-math`, a better solution is `abc_{\symup d}`, or else set `\mathrm` to work as `symup` by default.  The `\mathrm` command sets `d` in the main text font.

Here’s an example of why you might want upright math letters to be different from the main font, and some of the examples are superscripts.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}, 
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}
\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Euler equations]

This sets Euler’s equations in ISO style, in which the constants e, i and π are set upright.  It additionally sets the upright math letters to Neo Euler, an OTF conversion of the AMS Euler math font by Hermann Zapf.  It’s a good match for his famous font, Palatino, and I use clones of Palatino as both the text and the math font.  The digits, italic `x` symbol and the upright operator names sin and cos are from Palatino (by way of Adobe, URW Palladio, pxfonts and Asana Math).

Without changing the `\symup` alphabet and using it, the symbol for the imaginary unit would look like the letter i in sin and d*x* would look like you were integrating the variable *x*.

If you use the default Latin Modern Math font, you might try CMU Serif Upright Italic (`cmunui.otf`) as an alternative for upright math letters.  This is an OpenType conversion of Donald Knuth’s unslanted Computer Modern Italic font.

### Using Legacy Encodings

It’s also possible to achieve very similar output in PDFLaTeX by loading `newpxmath`, either `newpxtext` or `tgpagella`, and then loading AMS Euler as a symbol font.  Since many mathematical texts want to set a small number of constants as upright letters, this is another viable approach.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerup}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upi}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"69}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upe}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"65}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Euler equations in PDFLaTeX]

AMS Euler is part of `amsfonts`, so I took the character codes [from the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf).  The standard legacy codings are all in the [LaTeX Font Encoding guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf).  Other legacy fonts with U encodings should include font tables in their documentation.

If you use the default Computer Modern font, you might try the upright italic shape of Computer Modern (`cmr{m}{ui}`) to get upright Latin letters and the `upgreek` package to get upright Greek.