# Creating bold and non-italic equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, bold, italic

I am trying to write an equation in bold and non italic but I can't get it to work because I also want to write a D with two dots over it. Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
\text{\boldsymbol{{M} \ddot{D}} + KD = F}. 
\end{equation}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *non cursive*? Do you want to write all your math in *non-italic*? If so, you could find a way to do that by following [this question and its answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39515/is-there-a-way-to-set-math-mode-font-non-italic).

Comment: I have multiply equations but this is the only equation that I want non-italic.

Comment: Try `\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M \ddot{D}} + KD = F.
\end{equation}`

Comment: `\mathbf{M}\ddot{\mathbf{D}}`

Comment: Thank you! It worked now

Answer (score 2):

Let me spell out @egreg and my comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
@egreg proposition:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}\ddot{\mathbf{D}} + KD = F. 
\end{equation}

My proposition:
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{M \ddot{D}} + KD = F. 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there should be no `\text`: you want a math formula.

If you use `\boldsymbol`, you get bold (math) italic. If you want bold (math) upright, the command is `\mathbf`.

Also, each letter should be specified with a distinct call of `\mathbf` and the double dot (second derivative in Newton notation) should not be bold.

Hence

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M} \ddot{\mathbf{D}} + KD = F
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The formula is not at all clear, though, but you know better.

[image]