# Can't use some AMS binary operators

Tags: amsmath

I'm using the `amsmath` package, and I want to put in a sentence, the not similar binary operator. I tried this:

```
... bla bla $ a \nsim b $ bla bla ...
```

I get the error:

> "Undefined control sequence".

By the way, if I put `\sim` it works, but I want negate it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need `\usepackage{amssymb}`, which isn't automatically loaded by `amsmath`.

Comment: Hey thank you. Oh sorry i don't know this thing, i thought that all i need is inside amsmath. Noob question :)

Comment: See [What does each AMS package do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32103/5764)

Comment: Please consider accepting answers that you consider best solved your problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\nsim` is listed in table 69 of the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, under the caption

> AMS Negated Binary Relations

In section 1.1 of the document, we find

> “AMS” means to use the AMS packages, viz. `amssymb` and/or `amsmath`.

Actually most of the symbols with that tag require `amssymb` and this is the case for `\nsim`.

[image]

Note that the result of `\not\sim` is rather different, so the final answer is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
... bla bla bla $a \nsim b$ bla bls ...

\end{document}
```