# Transitioning to mathtools - environment proof undefined

Tags: theorems, amsthm, mathtools

I am new to LaTeX and I was using the amsthm package in order to write proofs by using the proof environment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Stuff in here
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Proof in here
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I then decided to use the mathtools package, since it contains more symbols and corrects some of the amsthm's bugs. However, if I substitute the line

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

for

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

I get the error "! LaTeX Error: Environment proof undefined."

Is there a way to correct this? 
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`amsthm` and `mathtools` are unrelated.  `mathtools` updates and extends `amsmath`.

you still need `amsthm` if you want the `proof` environment.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared things up! I was thinking that amsthm was 'contained' by amsmath.

Comment: But `mathtools` loads `amsthm` anyway no?

Comment: `mathtools` does not load `amsthm`. According to this [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/what-does-each-ams-package-do), `amsmath`, `amsthm` and `amssymb` are different packages. Even though they share the 'ams' name, they must be loaded separately. Therefore, `mathtools` only loads `amsmath`. @percusse

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé Ah of course. A moment of dyslexic reading, I kept on reading amsmath all the way..

Answer (score 0):

I think the document class might be a source of confusion.

The document class `amsart.cls` loads the package `amsthm.sty`, but since your using the document class `book.cls` you need to manually load the package `amsthm.sty`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @karlkoeller -- slight correction here ... `amsart` *incorporates the features and code* of `amsthm`, but with slightly different defaults for spacing and fonts.  input directed at these features is identical, but output will differ slightly.  (for comparison, `amsart` does actually load `amsmath` with `\RequirePackage`.)