# Spacing before section heading is uneven

Tags: sectioning, vertical-spacing

In every chapter the first section heading has a problem of overlapping with the previous paragraph.

Here is the code and I'm new to latex.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfig} %for sub figure
\usepackage{epsfig} %for using eps figure
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{epstopdf}%using eps fig in pdflatex compailing
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy,hhmmss]{datetime}
%\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{caption} %to remove numbering in the figure captions
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}   %used to use different bib styles
\usepackage{hyperref} %used to han­dle cross-ref­er­enc­ing com­mands in LaTeX to pro­duce hy­per­text links in the doc­u­ment.
\usepackage{setspace} %Pro­vides sup­port for set­ting the spac­ing be­tween lines in a doc­u­ment.
\usepackage{rotating} %used to rotate the figures, tables sideways
\usepackage{multirow} %used to merge the rows of table
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %pro­vides ex­ten­sive fa­cil­i­ties, both for con­struct­ing head­ers and foot­ers
\usepackage{sectsty}  %used to set the section and chapter heading font size
%\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}%to remove the colon in the caption
%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  %used to type special characters, accent letters
\usepackage{array}
%
%\usepackage{lineno}
%\linenumbers    %package and the command are used to put line numbers
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hvfloat,lipsum}
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}%to remove the colon in the caption of the figures and tables.

\usepackage{ragged2e} % text justify
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % to set margind for individual pages
%\geometry{
%left={1in},
%right={1in},
%top={1.5in},
%bottom={1in},
%}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} % abbrivations
%\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} %  To get space between text and numbering in toc
%\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{3em}
%\cftsetindents{subsection}{3em}{4em}


%\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref} %toc in multi line
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % to remove word break
%\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page numbers (and reset to 1)
\usepackage{pslatex} %Times font
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\newcommand{\listofnotations}{\chapter*{Nomenclature}\input{7_Expansions.tex}}
%\newcommand{\addnotation}[2]
%{\begin{tabbing}12345678901234\=\kill \parbox{0.75in}{\hfill$#1$} \> \parbox[t]{5in}{#2 
%(page \pageref{#2})}
%\end{tabbing}}
%\newcommand{\newnot}[1]{\label{#1}} 

%\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus0.3ex minus0.0ex}
%\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % the line spacing is 1.5
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}

%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt} %removes padding after figures 
\usepackage{mathptmx}%Times new roman nearest match
\chapterfont{\LARGE}
\sectionfont{\large}


%Command             10pt    11pt    12pt
%\tiny               5       6       6
%\scriptsize         7       8       8
%\footnotesize       8       9       10
%\small              9       10      10.95
%\normalsize         10      10.95   12
%\large              12      12      14.4
%\Large              14.4    14.4    17.28
%\LARGE              17.28   17.28   20.74
%\huge               20.74   20.74   24.88
%\Huge               24.88   24.88   24.88

%\numberwithin{figure}{section}
%\numberwithin{table}{section}

%\setlength{\topmargin}{1.5in} % top margin is .5 in
%\newgeometry{top=1.5in, bottom=1in}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1in, outer=1in, inner=1.5in]{geometry}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.7in} % left margin is 1 in on right pages
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in} % same for left pages, 2-sided document




\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}

%\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1: }}{\hspace{\stretch{1}}\rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}


\newcommand\N{\mathfrak{N}}
\newcommand\F{\mathbf{F}}
\newcommand\T{\mathbf{T}}









%\makeindex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)


\thispagestyle{empty} %produces the title page without page number
\newgeometry{top=1.5in, bottom=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in}
\doublespacing{\include{Front_Back_Matter/1_Titlepage}}
\restoregeometry

\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{a}
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{Front_Back_Matter/2_Dedication}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{a}
\newpage  %these two lines produces a blank page in the beginning of the thesis.

\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{Front_Back_Matter/3_Declaration}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{a}
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{Front_Back_Matter/4_Certificate}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{a}
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{Front_Back_Matter/5_Acknowledgement}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{Front_Back_Matter/6_Thesisabsract}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

%\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\phantom{a}
%\newpage

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures} 
\listoffigures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables} 
\listoftables

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{a}
\newpage

%\newpage
%%include{Front_Back_Matter/8_Symbols}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\begin{center}
%Department of Mathematical and Computational Sciences, \\National Institute of Technology Karnataka, \\Surathkal, Mangalore-575025
%\\
%{\em E-mail:} smhegde@nitk.ac.in, suresh.dara@gmail.com
%\end{center}
%\maketitle

%\begin{abstract}
%
%\end{abstract}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{a}
\newpage



\pagenumbering{arabic}

%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\include{Front_Back_Matter/chap1}

\include{chap_1_Introduction}




\newpage
\include{chap_2}

\newpage
\include{chap_3}
%
%

\newpage
\include{chap_4}

\newpage
\include{chap_5}


\newpage
\include{chap_6}



\newpage
\bibliographystyle{Bibliography/apa}
\nocite{*}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{Bibliography/mydatabase}


\newpage
\include{pub}

\newpage
\include{Front_Back_Matter/My_Biodata}


\end{document}
```

Comment: For reference, you should read [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) We're usually only interested in the detail that replicates the problem...

Comment: Hello! It's not really possible for us to help you because we can't run your code. Please see the link @Werner posted. Sorry, this is off the point, but you might want to pay closer attention to what packages you use. Some of your packages and commands might conflict (like `setspace` with `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`), some you load multiple times, some are redundant (for example `mathtools,amssymb,amsthm` [should suffice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32100/172164) for all ams packages), etc. This makes it difficult to de-bug and more likely you run into errors in the first place.